# Subsetting a dataframe in R including observations that satisfy condition

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to randomly subset dataframe with condition that if the observation with alpha=1 is included in a subset, then all observation which has alpha=1 must be included in the subset. I simplify data, so it looks like this.

```
 df
 alpha beta gamma
 1    5     2
 1    6     3
 1    5     3
 2    3     2
 2    5     9
 2    2     6
 3    3     4
 3    4     7
 3    3     8
 4    3     4
 4    8     3
 4    4     9
 5    9     8
 5    5     5
 5    3     5
```

What command should I use to get subsets like the following?

```
 df1
 alpha beta gamma
 1    5     2
 1    6     3
 1    5     3
 3    3     4
 3    4     7
 3    3     8
 5    9     8
 5    5     5
 5    3     5

 df2
 alpha beta gamma
 2    3     2
 2    5     9
 2    2     6
 4    3     4
 4    8     3
 4    4     9
 5    9     8
 5    5     5
 5    3     5

 df3
 alpha beta gamma
 1    5     2
 1    6     3
 1    5     3
 2    3     2
 2    5     9
 2    2     6
 5    9     8
 5    5     5
 5    3     5
```

Specifically, the first observation in df with numbers (1,5,2) is randomly fell in subset df1 and df3. If so, it must follow that 2nd and 3d observations in df (1,6,3) and (1,5,3) are also included in subsets df1 and df2.

I hope that my question is clear. Please help.

Comment: You need to clarify the subsetting criteria as it was not very clear.

Comment: The criteria is that if the observation with alpha =1 was included in subset, then all observation with aplha =1 also must be included in the subset. If the observation with alpha =4 was included in subset, then all observation with aplha =4also must be included in the subset and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str <- "alpha,beta,gamma
1,5,2
1,6,3
1,5,3
2,3,2
2,5,9
2,2,6
3,3,4
3,4,7
3,3,8
4,3,4
4,8,3
4,4,9
5,9,8
5,5,5
5,3,5"

df <- read.csv(textConnection(str))

df[df$alpha %in% sample(unique(df$alpha), 3), ]
```

Output

```
   alpha beta gamma
4      2    3     2
5      2    5     9
6      2    2     6
10     4    3     4
11     4    8     3
12     4    4     9
13     5    9     8
14     5    5     5
15     5    3     5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. R says:

"Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument"

Comment: I works perfectly for me, so then there must be difference between your and my data. Can you add the output of `dput(df)` to your question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It really works. Thank you very much!